# How internally JVM interpret 010 or 0110 Number

Tags: java

Why java JVM consider int i = 010 or int i = 0110 as an octal value , instead of integer value 10 or 110 ?

Comment: Why not ? It's the spec.

Comment: It's not the JVM, but _javac_, that does that.

Comment: See [Section 3.10.1 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

Comment: It's in the language spec not vm spec.

Comment: @Sunil You might want to edit the question.  I would suggest "Why does the Java language support octal literals?" or something like that.

Comment: But How internally compiler , perform this conversion.

Answer (score 5):

When Java was designed C and C++ were its biggest competitors. The designers of Java wanted to make Java like C and C++ so that programmers proficient in these languages would find the transition easier. Much of Java's syntax, including octal literals, was inspired by C or C++ syntax.

The octal values have nothing to do with the virtual machine. The octal value exists only in the source code. The translation is performed by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Not only in Java, this behaviour is in almost all programming languages like C, C++ etc. As per the programming spec, if a number is prefixed with **0**, then it will be treated as an octal number and if it is prefixed with **0x**, then it will be treated as hexadecimal number.

And specifically in Java, if you want to declare binary number, then you have to prefix it with **0b**. But you can use this only in `Java 7 or later(if exists)`.

Comment: Ok, But What about then Binary format, Why not its consider as binary ?

Comment: But How can we represent Binary Format then as you said we need to use prefix **0b** but 'only in Java 7 or later' then in lower version of Java (say Java 1.4 or 5 or 6), Is this not possible to declare Binary Number

Comment: @SunilSingh Well i am not sure, but I think it is not possible to declare a binary number prior to java 7.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't confuse what the `javac` Java compile does and what the JVM does.

The `javac` compiler foolows the Java spec and convention of similar languages to treat numbers start with `0` as octal, `0x` as hex and in Java 7 `0b` as binary.

The JVM only see binary numbers not text and so it has no idea whether you used 0100 or 0x40 or 64 or 0xb1000000 because the number has been converted.

In short, the JVM doesn't have any idea about `010`, its the javac compilers job because thats what the language spec says it should do.